# uninstall a package for a particular version of python using conda

Tags: python, conda

I have Python 2 and Python 3 **BOTH** within the **same** conda environment.

Yes, that's right. I don't have 2 separate environments...but just one. And it has Python 2 and Python 3 installed in it.

First question: Is this bad practice? I'm starting to feel like it is.

Say I want to install Pandas, but for the Python 3 install. And explicitly NOT the Python 2 install. How do I do this?

I read documentation but couldn't find the flag I feel like should exist for this to be done.

Comment: quite easy, source activate the version of python you want to install the package to, pip install the package, and then deactivate. It will only be installed to the active version.

Comment: How did you even do this?  Could you please post the results from `conda list --revisions`?  I'd like to see what the environment actually has installed.

Comment: I'm curious how you even did this. As far as I know, `conda` will switch over all the dependencies and can only have one version of Python in a given environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'd consider this bad practice. As a general rule of thumb, software that requires different/specific versions serve as good delimiters for splitting off into separate envs.

I'm not sure that `conda` can handle this directly, but `pip` can since you can have multiple versions of it installed side-by-side.  Namely, installing packages with `pip2` and `pip3` should install to the Python 2 and 3 `site-packages`, respectively.  Just verify first with `which pip2` and `which pip3` that this corresponds to the Python installations you wish to modify.  It is a very common mistake to use `pip2` and it turn out to still be the default system one and not a conda one.

As I mentioned in a comment, I'd like to see the full history of your env (`conda list --revisions` to provide more specific suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple python versions with anaconda.
Refer to this on how to manage multiple versions of python:

https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html

The gist is that you can have multiple environments.

To install/uninstall a package, you first activate the specific environment (`activate` or `source activate`) and then proceed to install/uninstall

Comment: Right, but I have 2 versions of python...within one environment. I'm not talking about having 2 different virtual envs

Comment: well you're not supposed to do it like that. Read the docs I linked to!

Comment: anyways, just so you know, each python installation comes with its own pip. use the pip for the specific python version to install packages

Comment: I try not to mix pip and conda installs in the same environment if I can help it...but yeah I guess it's not okay to have 2 Pythons in one env. that's probably the take-home message.